# Why is this 'list index out of range' happening?

Tags: python

So I have a `csv` file that I am reading with Python, and this is the format of the first attribute: `'2011-01-01 00:00:00'` i.e. it is a string that has the date and a timestamp, separate by a space. When I call `split()` on this code, I get back `['2011-01-01', '00:00:00']`, which **very clearly** is a list of `size = 2`.

This is the code I am working with:

```
for line in train_data:
    datetime = line[0]    # get first attribute of line
    datetime_array = datetime.split(' ')    # split on space
    print datetime_array[0]
```

The above code works fine, and prints out the dates only, in the expected format of `2011-01-01`.

However, if I want to get the time string, I change my code to this:

```
for line in train_data:
    datetime = line[0]    # get first attribute of line
    datetime_array = datetime.split(' ')    # split on space
    print datetime_array[1]    # changed index from 0 to 1
```

I get an `IndexError: list index out of range` error thrown with the above code.

*Interestingly enough*, if I do this:

```
for line in train_data:
    datetime = line[0]
    datetime_array = datetime.split(' ')
    size = len(datetime_array)    # size = 2
    print datetime_array[size - 1]    # size - 1 = 1
```

The output is expected, so I get `00:00:00`

Can someone tell me why this happens? Why do I get the error when I explicitly specify the index?

Comment: Is it possible that the first line matches what you expect but later lines don't? For example, the last line of the file might be blank.

Comment: You have this in `for` cycle, maybe it throws index error only on the last line? Or there is an empty one? You can try it by using Try&Except, where you will print full line if it fails. Alternatively, you can use datetime_array[-1], which will print last element.

Comment: Are you sure size is 2? Why not just print size for testing and check if there are _really_ two elements for all lines?

Comment: `datetime_array[size - 1] ` will get an element even if there is only 1

Comment: perhaps it's a problematic csv row (first line of description or blank input). try to debug it (by printing each line) and you will detect this bad input

Comment: This is almost certainly an error with some line of your CSV. Please check your CSV file to make sure that all dats and times are in the correct format. You might want to put a debugging `print` statement which prints out each line in your CSV to find the errant line.

Comment: Thanks guys. I really really spaced out and made an amateur mistake. The entire file matched what I was looking for except the first line, which was causing the error. Thanks all~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was throwing that `IndexError: list index out of range` error because the first line of my csv file contained the attribute name, in this case, `datetime`. Of course, this means the list is just `['datetime']`, which has `size = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine under the assumption there is a whitespace between the date and the hour.

The problem is - somewhere there isn't.

To find out where, and why, use this:

```
line_number = 1
for line in train_data:
    datetime = line[0]    # get first attribute of line
    datetime_array = datetime.split(' ')    # split on space
    if len(datetime_array) < 2:
        print "The following line does not conform to expected format:"
        print line
        print "line number: %d" % line_number
    line_number += 1
```

This will print all lines that are not in the format you expect.